# DotNetNuke Starter Kit Version 05.06.01 creates an old manifest file

Tags: module, manifest, dotnetnuke, starter-kits

I installed the starter kit version 05.06.01 on visual studio 2010 and when I create a compiled module, the first line of the manifest file is:

```
<dotnetnuke version="3.0" type="Module">
```

Shouldn't it be version 5.0

Thanks.

Comment: Where I can download dnn Starter Kit for development of skin and module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starter Kit's manifest uses the older "Module" manifest type, for which the current version is 3.0. This is not related to the DotNetNuke major version, or the version of the module described in the manifest. Module manifest type is used only to package modules, and it is compatible with DNN4 and DNN5.

In DNN5 it is better to use the manifest type "Package", version 5.0. More specifically, "Package" is the manifest type used by the [new extension installer](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1847/The-New-Extension-Installer-Manifest-Part-1-Introduction.aspx). "Package" type can be used to install all extensions: modules, skins, authentication providers, and so on. Package manifest type is not compatible with DNN4, with one exception, authentication providers (since 4.6.2).

Starter Kit has not been updated to the new package system yet, but you can try [Christoc's DotNetNuke Module Development Template](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/) to get DNN5 manifests.